# How much does the temperature increase after the saturation of the material due to the magnetocaloric effect?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, magnetic-fields, entropy

If we assume a point in the M-H curve  of matter that is the complete saturation of matter, from this point onwards (with increase in magnetic field), do we have an increase in temperature in relation to the magnetocaloric effect?
I think that after the matter is completely saturated, with the increase of the magnetic field, its magnetism remains constant and the magnetic entropy does not change and we do not have an increase in temperature. As a result, after complete saturation of matter and with increasing magnetic field, there is no magnetocaloric effect. Is this assumption correct?
[image: M-H curve]

What is the magnetic entropy curve (Sm(H,T)) after saturation?

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes, once magnetically saturated, a crystal temperature will not change further with increasing magnetic fields as there is nothing to magnetize anymore (magnetization depends highly on the spin state of a crystal).

As you understand (I assume you do, otherwise I don't think you would've asked the question), a change in magnetization of a cristal results in a change of temperature since it changes the magnetic entropy of the crystal.

> When M rise, S$_M$ lowers and T rise as well as the energy stored in the moving/free spins has to go somewher, and it goes to phonons. When demagnetizing the same cristal, the temperature will lower as S$_M$ rise, the spins will take the energy from the phonons. This kind of break of symmetry is what allows long range magnetic state to survive at higher temperature than 0K 2D materials (you can read more about Wagner-Mermin theorem for magnetization).

Magnetocaloric effect depends on the change of magetization M. Here, as the Maxwell equation yields:
$-\Delta S_M = \mu_0 V \int_0^H \left(\frac{d M}{d T}\right) d H'$
and 
$\Delta T_{adiabatic} = -\frac{T}{c_p (H)} \Delta S_M$
In addition, after a time $\tau$, the cristal temperature will be the same as its environnment.

In other words, once your cristal is saturated, which means that all the magnetizable charges/particles/etc are magnetized, you can't further megnetize it with increasing the magnetic field. This in turn means that the magnetic entropy is at its lowest and can't change further (as there are no more free spins), which means that there is no more temperature change possible.

Hope it helps, cheers